# A question about connectedness in complex analysis by Lars Ahlfors

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I was reading Complex analysis by Lars Ahlfors but got stuck on a line. 
" Neighborhoods and open sets on E
are defined as on any metric space, but an open set on E need not be open
when regarded as a subset of S. To avoid confusion neighborhoods and
open sets on E are often referred to as relative neighborhoods and relatively
open sets. As an example, if we regard the closed interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$ as
a subspace of R, then the semiclosed interval $0 \leq x <1$ is relatively open,
but not open in R."

Can someone explain why the semiclosed interval is not open in R

Comment: Consider neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a more ?

Comment: @AKADeath an open set contains an open set around each of it's points. Any open set about the origin must contain points that are negative. Conclude.

Comment: How is "open set" defined in that book? Doesn't it say that for a set $A$ to be open, each point of $A$ must have a neighbourhood which is contained in $A$?

Comment: What does relatively open means ?

Comment: So the statement is saying that relatively it got open on the one end but it is not fully open ,thus closed, in R

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space and $E\subseteq X$ then a set $A$ is relatively open with respect to $E$ iff we can write this set as $A=E\cap U$ where $U$ is an open set. Further a set that is not open is not necessarily closed (you seem to suggest that in the last line of your last comment).

Comment: What is E ? What is S ? Do they relate in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that $\mathbb R$ is equipped with its usual topology.

Stated is that $[0,1)$ is a set that is open subspace $[0,1]$ equipped with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$.

This is true because we can write $[0,1)=[0,1]\cap(-\infty,1)$ where $(-\infty,1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$.

Next to that $[0,1)$ is *not* an open set of $\mathbb R$.

This because a set $U$ open in $\mathbb R$ such that $0\in U\subseteq[0,1)$ *does not exist*, showing that $0$ is not an interior point of $[0,1)$.

(a set is open iff it contains all its interior points)

Thinking of $\mathbb R$ as a metric space you could also say that we cannot find an open ball centered at $0$ and contained in $[0,1)$.